# What does misaligned_stack_error_ mean?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash

I have some crashes with misaligned_stack_error_ after migration to new cocos2d-iphone version(3.1). One harmless line crashes my code:
`ccColor3B colorPH = [[self node].color ccColor3b];`
What can be reason of this crash? What does misaligned_stack_error_ mean?

Comment: Long-story-short: memory accesses like to use n-byte alignment (where generally n=4 or n=8) and the stack is no different.  This is not going to be an easy problem to solve and I would recommend single-stepping through the code and try to narrow down where the issue lies (the statement you post looks innocent enough so it's possible the stack has already been corrupted before that statement).

Comment: Thanks! Could you show code example that can corrupt stack?

Comment: Err, not easily to be honest.  It's quite an uncommon error TBH, and therefore difficult to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason. As I've already said I migrated to new cocos2d version. In my old code I had a method in category for CCNode. It returns structure:

```
-(ccColor3B)color
{
    return (ccColor3B){255,255,255};
}
```

But it the new cocos2d version developers added new property in CCNode that calls `color` too but returns object(CCColor*). 
Thanks!